# how to use multiple inline assertions in Frege

Tags: frege

for the sake of self-checking examples, I got the following code running:

```
assert :: Bool -> Bool -> String -> IO ()
assert actual expected description
    | expected == actual     = do { print "" }   -- need a better way to do nothing
    | otherwise              = error description

main _ = do
    assert (odd 2) false "2 is not odd"
    assert (odd 3) true  "3 is odd"
```

I know this is not perfect (and advice is more than welcome) but the current issue is that when I put the definition of assert into a module util.Assertions then using two assertions fails to compile with

```
build/realworld/chapter2/FunctionApplication.java:168: error: cannot access ?
              Assertions.?._assert?.apply(
                        ^
class file for util.Assertions$? not found
1 error
E .../Real_World_Frege/chapter2/FunctionApplication.fr:24: java compiler errors are most likely caused by erronous
native definitions
```

It works when I have only one assertion, so the class itself is on the CP and the module import works in principle. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `assert` function results in a type of the form `m ()` where `m` is a `Monad`. The best way to "do nothing" is therefore to just

```
return ()
```

For the second part of your question I can not really imagine what is wrong. Please arrange your github repo so that I could download it and try for myself. Also, give the compile command you use and the working directory.

(Btw, you should use a terminal emulator that can display Unicode. 
Under Windows, try `chcp 65001`)

Comment: I thought I had it but it needs more work. The latest state is in the repo.

Comment: I compile with this [gradle build](https://gist.github.com/Dierk/6566983)

It seems that the -sp flag does not work and one
a) has to give _all_ files separately to the command line and
b) has to care about the proper compile sequence manually.
Is this by intention?

Comment: The -sp flag is used only when the -make flag is given. In all other cases, the compiler uses only class files (on the classpath) or the file(s) on the command line (in the order given). Thus, in most cases it should be enough to say: `java -jar fregec.jar -d bin -make path/to/your/main/module/here.fr`

Comment: I downloaded your sources, commented the assert function in FunctionApplication.fr and uncommented the util.Assertions import. Then the following command compiled the thing without problems: java -jar ~/frege/fregec.jar -v -d bin -make -sp Real_World_Frege-master/ Real_World_Frege-master/chapter2/FunctionApplication.fr

Comment: It's cool to have asked late in the night and have the answer the next Sunday noon! Thanks for that. Much appreciated. The above works. It triggers the next question about how to compile a whole source tree, though, but I will ask separately.

Comment: Yeah, no problem with that, Dierk. Today we have cold, foggy weather around here in the mountains where I am on vacation currently.